# inline-block will not change elements in my unordered list to horizontal display

Tags: html, css

I have three list items that are in a unordered list between some text. When I change the display to inline block it still keeps the vertical orientation. What is keeping the list items from being displayed horizontally?

```
div class="row">
      <div class="icons">
    <ul class="social">
        <li><a href="#" class="button social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="button social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="button social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.social{
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .social li{
   display:inline-block; 
  }
```

You need to put display:inline-block on li not on ul.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.social > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.